# How to write table in overleaf?

Tags: tables, sectioning, code, pseudocode

I hope you are doing very well. I am writing a report for my class.
[image]

I need to add code like this in my latex report. But I haven't found any similar example from google. I just recently started using latex. I know it is inpropriate to ask this question. Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the [`listings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, the documentation is at that link and can create code listings that look like that

Comment: Overleaf also has some documentation on [code listings](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing).  It also has some documentation on [tables](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables), but that's nothing like the output you've shown, so I don't think you want to be looking at how to make tables for this question.  You'll probably need to make a table eventually, but that's not what you've shown here.